# Can a graph have the same number of strongly connected components and weakly connected components?

Tags: graph-theory, network

Exactly what the title says.
Can a graph have the same number of strongly connected components and weakly connected components?

I am using networkX and have the same number for a dataset for both weakly and strongly connected components.

I believe that it can but I was wondering if it means anything for a graph to have this coincidence.

Comment: Obviously this phenomenon is possible; for example consider two vertices and both directed edges between them.  As for the more subtle question of what it means, I don't know.

Answer (score 1):

It means that every weakly connected component is strongly connected.  This implies the digraph is the union of disjoint strongly connected digraphs.

Mathematically, there's no problems with this: there's plenty of digraphs where this occurs, such as the union of directed cycles.

It might have some significance from a network science perspective.  (Or it could  be some artifact: e.g. NetworkX may have interpreted an undirected graph as a digraph with edges directed in both directions.)

Comment: Well that happened to a directed graph describing a network of roads where by default a road connecting two locations is interpreted as an edge directed to both direction. When O loaded the file as a directed graph I had the same number of wcc and scc and then when I turned it into an undirected graph the number of connected component subgraphs was also the same. I just found it too high a coincidence...